# Problem with downloading files from play market and websites

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, download-manager

I have nexus 5 (android 4.4.2, TeamWin Recovery Project, root). Recently, problem with downloading files from play market and websites appeared.

I see infinite downloading in the play market. I see infinite work of the donwload manager process in the action bar, when I download some stuff from website (for example, when I try to download something from my HTTP local file server).

Sometimes I can solve my problem to restart smartphone, to clear data/cache play market app and download manager procces. But the problem occurs again.

Also I tried to boot into recovery, clear cache, fix permissions, and reboot. These actions have fixed my problem, but the problem appeared again.

[image]
`(Click on image to show larger preview)`

Comment: What rom are you using? Just rooted stock rom?

Comment: @Zlatty, yes, I use just rooted stock rom.

Comment: I wonder if it is an issue with the storage. I had issues like this with a 4.2 rom on my Note II. I'll suggest an answer that might work below.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Play Store is having some issues writing on your phone. However, given that your phone is new(ish) and that there is nothing that's going on a SD card, it makes me think that the Play Store is getting confused.

Depending on what GAPPS package you installed, there could be a variety of tweaks that are done to the package. I would double check with goo.im or XDA to see hat GAPPS to install with your rom/device. Perhaps removing the Play Store, then installing a GAPPS with the right play store app would fix the problem.

Additionally, it could be that you have your runtime on ART instead of Dalvik and the Play Store is glitching up. To check your runtime, go to Settings -> Developer Options -> Select runtime.

Comment: really, I have ART runtime. However, I chose this runtime on day of purchase of the Nexus, and I had no problems for a while. Thanks for the advice. I'll try to reinstall GAPPS.